# How to declare an array of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to iterate over all the elements of a static array of strings in the best possible way. I want to be able to declare it on one line and easily add/remove elements from it without having to keep track of the number. Sounds really simple, doesn't it?

Possible non-solutions:

```
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("abc");
b.push_back("xyz");

for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i] << endl;
```

Problems - no way to create the vector on one line with a list of strings

Possible non-solution 2:

```
string list[] = {"abc", "xyz"};
```

Problems - no way to get the number of strings automatically (that I know of).

There must be an easy way of doing this.

Comment: The [boost assign library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It makes assigning constants to containers easier than ever.

Answer (score 110):

C++ 11 added initialization lists to allow the following syntax:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"Hello", "World"};
```

Support for this C++ 11 feature was added in at least [GCC 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and only in [Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable).

Comment: 2018. Just starting C++ and did quite some research regarding flexible arrays. Ended up just using vectors...

Comment: Do you know how can that be declared `static const` in an object definition?

Answer (score 37):

You can concisely initialize a `vector<string>` from a statically-created `char*` array:

```
char* strarray[] = {"hey", "sup", "dogg"};
vector<string> strvector(strarray, strarray + 3);
```

This copies all the strings, by the way, so you use twice the memory.  You can use Will Dean's suggestion to replace the magic number 3 here with arraysize(str_array) -- although I remember there being some special case in which that particular version of arraysize might do Something Bad (sorry I can't remember the details immediately).  But it very often works correctly.

Also, if you're really gung-ho about the one line thingy, you can define a variadic macro so that a single line such as `DEFINE_STR_VEC(strvector, "hi", "there", "everyone");` works.

Comment: Since `strarray` is in a header, won't it violate the one definition rule?

Answer (score 22):

> Problems - no way to get the number of strings automatically (that i know of).

There is a bog-standard way of doing this, which lots of people (including MS) define macros like `arraysize` for:

```
#define arraysize(ar)  (sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]))
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use something like this: `template<typename T, size_t N> inline size_t arraysize(T (&ar)[N]) { return N; }`  (Inline keyword not necessary, but used to document the function's intent.  A modern compiler should theoretically be able to return the entire function, I believe.

Comment: This fails for pointers. Counting array elements should be done a different way in C++.

Answer (score 8):

Declare an array of strings in C++ like this  : `char array_of_strings[][]`

For example : `char array_of_strings[200][8192];`

will hold 200 strings, each string having the size 8kb or 8192 bytes.

use `strcpy(line[i],tempBuffer);`  to put data in the array of strings.

Comment: FYI, char array_of_strings[][] can't accept C++ strings, be sure to convert to char* first. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: Since `array_of_strings` is in a header, won't it violate the one definition rule?

Answer (score 7):

One possiblity is to use a NULL pointer as a flag value:

```
const char *list[] = {"dog", "cat", NULL};
for (char **iList = list; *iList != NULL; ++iList)
{
    cout << *iList;
}
```

Comment: What does char ** actually mean? In java, would it be a list of strings?

Comment: @Doomsknight: In this case, yes.  In the first line I define an array of `char*`.  In memory, this gets laid out as 3 pointers - one points to "dog", one points to "cat" and one is left NULL.  I can take a pointer to that first pointer, and get a `char**` - a pointer to pointer to char.  When I increment that, I move the char** to point to the next item in the list - a pointer to the pointer that points to "cat", then I increment again, and get a pointer that points to the NULL pointer, and I know I'm done.
(

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `begin` and `end` functions from the Boost range library to easily find the ends of a primitive array, and unlike the macro solution, this will give a compile error instead of broken behaviour if you accidentally apply it to a pointer.

```
const char* array[] = { "cat", "dog", "horse" };
vector<string> vec(begin(array), end(array));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    const char* const list[] = {"zip", "zam", "bam"};
    const size_t len = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        std::cout << list[i] << "\n";

    const std::vector<string> v(list, list + len);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can use Will Dean's suggestion [`#define arraysize(ar)  (sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]))`] to replace the magic number 3 here with arraysize(str_array) -- although I remember there being some special case in which that particular version of arraysize might do Something Bad (sorry I can't remember the details immediately). But it very often works correctly.

The case where it doesn't work is when the "array" is really just a pointer, not an actual array. Also, because of the way arrays are passed to functions (converted to a pointer to the first element), it doesn't work across function calls even if the signature looks like an array — `some_function(string parameter[])` is really `some_function(string *parameter)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that macro, might I suggest this one:

```
template<typename T, int N>
inline size_t array_size(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X)   (sizeof(array_size(X)) ? (sizeof(X) / sizeof((X)[0])) : -1)
```

1) We want to use a macro to make it a compile-time constant; the function call's result is not a compile-time constant.

2) However, we don't want to use a macro because the macro could be accidentally used on a pointer.  The function can only be used on compile-time arrays.

So, we use the defined-ness of the function to make the macro "safe"; if the function exists (i.e. it has non-zero size) then we use the macro as above.  If the function does not exist we return a bad value.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

const char* list[] = {"abc", "xyz"};
BOOST_FOREACH(const char* str, list)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::vector< std::string > v = boost::assign::list_of( "abc" )( "xyz" );
    std::copy(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator< std::string >( std::cout, "\n" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly declare an array of strings like `string s[100];`.
Then if you want to access specific elements, you can get it directly like `s[2][90]`. For iteration purposes, take the size of string using the
`s[i].size()` function.