# C++ Arrays Compile Time Error

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a C++ project.  I'm teaching myself C++ after using Java.  Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class dayType
{
private:
    string day;
    string week[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};


public:
    dayType()
    {
        day = "Monday";
        dayID = 0;
    }
};
```

There are more public functions, but I left those out because they aren't important here.  There is a compile time error on the array.  It says it is "Unable to resolve identifier: week", "unexpected token: {", and "unexpected token:}".  Can someone explain why this is happening?  If I declare it as "string week[7];" and then define the actual values in the functions, it works fine, but that's a pain.

Comment: Duplicate of problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284833/how-do-you-declare-arrays-in-a-c-header

Comment: You're using the Java syntax to initialize the string array `week[]`.

Comment: "define the actual values in the functions... a pain" - why?  It makes no sense to delocalise the member variable initialisation so that you have to consult both the declaration and the constructors to find non-default values....

Comment: What Lion mentioned is valid in C++11, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ feature you are looking for is "static class members". Here is the syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class dayType
{
private:
    string day;
    static string week[];

public:
    void Project113()
    {
        day = "Monday";
        dayID = 0;
    }
};


// Note that if the class definition is in a .H file, the following line should
// appear in exactly one .CPP file.
string dayType::week[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

Comment: I am not so sure. I think in this case he is just confused as to how to utilize OOP in C++. This does not seem like good design at all.

Answer (score 3):

That's just not possible in C++ to my knowledge. What exactly are you trying to do ? OOP isn't forced upon you in C++ as it is in Java or C#.

Also note that your function has a different name than your class name. This means that omitting the return type will result in a compiler error [thanks to Aditya Kumar for pointing that it does not result in void return type]

Comment: omitting the return type is an error in C++ if the function is not a constructor.